# How do I send the tag of a NSButtonCell together with his action?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a NSTableView with several columns. A column is made by NSButtonCells.
Each NSButtonCell has a specific tag.
This tag should be used inside the action method to specify which cell invoked the method.

Setting the tag for the cell is useless in my case, because the Sender object passed with the action is the NSTableView and not the NSButtonCell.

```
cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
                [cell setAction:@selector(openScreen:)];
                [cell setTag:tag];
                [cell setTarget:self];


-(void)openScreen:(id)sender //this sender is NSTableView, so i can't get the tag of the cell
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit, plz

Comment: @AnoopVaidya better now?

Comment: Can you try `[[sender superview] superview]`... i think this will do the trick.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It's the opposite problem to solve.

Comment: i'm not super well 'hearsed in actions, but can you pass the tag as an argument to the action somehow?  i.e `@selector(openScreen:tag)`.  i know that example wouldn't work, but something like that idea?

Edit: should (void)openScreen even have the sender parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to switch to view-based table views. In that case, this problem largely goes away, since the sender will be the `NSButton` instance, not the table view.

If you can't do that, then a question: how do you compute the tag that you want to use for the cell? Rather than using Astoria's answer (with my corrections as per the comment), you can just use the same logic you used to compute the tag for a given row,column to compute the value for the purposes of the action method.

Think about it: a cell-based table view typically reuses one cell for an entire column. It configures the cell by setting its object value (obtained from its data source or through bindings) and then lets the delegate configure it some more by calling `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`. If the cell is being assigned a tag, that's done at this point, but it's based, somehow, on the row and column.

Rather than asking the table view for a prepared cell, which goes through all of that rigmarole, you can just feed the `clickedRow` and `clickedColumn` into the same logic that you would use to assign the tag in the first place.

Another approach is to use bindings. For a cell-based table view, when a column is configured to use an `NSButtonCell`, the column has Action Invocation bindings. There's Target, which you bind to the target and specify a selector, and there's Argument, which is what is passed as the argument for the selector. In this case, the selector does not receive a "sender"; it just receives a generic argument. If the table column is bound to an array controller for its data, you can bind the Argument to the array controller, too. You can use the same or a different model key path.

Basically, in this case, you don't pass information from which you can look up the affected row, you directly pass data from or about the object being represented by that row. Like, if the table represents `Employee`s, you can pass the actual `Employee` instance to the action method and don't need to do a bunch of indirect lookup using rows, columns, tags, etc. to find the `Employee` to operate on.

You can also use this bindings approach in a view-based table view, but you bind the actual button object and you probably use the `NSTableCellView`'s `objectValue` as the Argument.